# How To Link External Javascript file To XSL?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, xslt

Currently iam doing a project in which Iam creating a website that involves html, xsl, xml, css and javascript. In my website I want to hide some information and be able to show it. I want to create a button in my XSL file for the purpose of expanding and collapsing some text. The button appears but the problem is the xsl doesn't recognize the javascript link so it wont expand/collapse.

So far I have tried the following codes in my xsl file:

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bookjavascript.js"></script>
```

Example:

```
 <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;script
 src="bookjavascript.js" language="Javascript"</xsl:text> <xsl:text
 disable-output-escaping="yes"> &gt;</xsl:text><xsl:text
 disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/script&gt;</xsl:text>
```

Example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    //I have inserted the javascript function directly. 
//]]>
</script>
```

javascript file

```
function expandCollapse(showHide) {

        var hideShowDiv = document.getElementById(showHide);
        var label = document.getElementById("expand");

        if (hideShowDiv.style.display == 'none') {
            label.innerHTML = label.innerHTML.replace("[+]", "[-]");
            hideShowDiv.style.display = 'block';            
        } else {
            label.innerHTML = label.innerHTML.replace("[-]", "[+]");
            hideShowDiv.style.display = 'none';

        }
    }
```

xsl file

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://localhost" exclude-result-prefixes="x" >

    <xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>



<script type="text/javascript" src="bookjavascript.js"></script>

<button onclick="expandCollapse('showHide');" id="expand">[+]Expand/Collapse</button>

<div id="showHide" style="display: none;">Javascript works</div>






<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/stylexsl.css" />
</head>
<body style=" font-family:Calibri;font-size:12pt;background-color:#FFF">

            <xsl:for-each select="x:books/x:book">




        <table style="   width: 70%;  " >

        <tr>


          <td style="  width:4%" align="right" >
                <img src="{x:contributor/x:profileImage}" style="width:60px;height:60px; " />

            </td>

            <td style="  width:25%; border-left: 1px solid black" >
                <div style="font-size:7pt"><a >28 October 2014<br/> </a><xsl:value-of select="a"/></div>
                <div style="font-size:7pt"><a><br/> </a><xsl:value-of select="x:author"/></div>
            </td>



        </tr>

        <tr>

          <td>

          </td>


          <td style=" width:70%; box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black; " colspan="2" >

            <h1  style="font-weight:bold; font-size:15px; text-decoration:underline"><xsl:value-of select="x:title"/></h1>

            <img src="{x:bookImage}" style="  height:400px;width:250px; border: 2px solid #045FB4; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;" />

            <div class="info-wrapper">
            <input type="checkbox" id="showhide"/>
            <label for="showhide">
                    <div class="more">Show more</div>
                    <div>Show less</div>
            </label>
            <div class="info"><xsl:value-of select="x:description"/></div>
            </div>




            <xsl:element name="a"><xsl:attribute name="href" ><xsl:value-of select="x:readmore" /></xsl:attribute>
            <span style="letter-spacing: 5px; font-size: 7px; ">READ MORE</span></xsl:element>





          </td>

        </tr>

        <tr><td height="40px"></td></tr>


    </table>









          </xsl:for-each>



           </body>
    </html>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your first example <script type="text/javascript" src="bookjavascript.js"></script> should work provided that javascript file can be found in the current directory.  Do you see any javascript errors in your browser?  Do you see that your browser is trying to load bookjavascript.js?

Comment: No I dont see any javascript errors. My javascript file is in the same directory as the xsl file. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you share your entire xsl file in your question?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have much more to offer than this...  You should move the <div> and <button> from <head> to <body>.  Clean up the white space in the XSL to make it easier for others to read.  I presume the table is displaying in your browser.  Check the NET calls to see if it is trying to load your js file.